# app/no-app error using firebase

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firebase

Having problems with firebase app initialization. Been looking for a solution for 2 days now. Still don't understand what the problem is the firebase initialization seems to be fine but for some reason it still gives me the error. I referred to my old code which was using an older version of firebase and initialized all the js files accordingly and yet it was still giving me problems. Refer below for more information, I would love it if anyone could solve this problem of mine

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp" >

<head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
<!--    <base href="/" />-->
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/banner.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/carousel.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/navbar.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/panel.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/text-banner.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/footer-distributed-with-contact-form.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/orderedlist.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/gallery.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/login.css"/>


</head>
<body data-ng-controller="myCtrl">


    <div>
        <div data-ng-view></div>
    </div>



</body>

    <script src="assets/js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!-- Firebase -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
    var config = {
        apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        authDomain: "xxxxxxxx",
        databaseURL: "xxxxxxxx",
        projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxx",
        messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxx"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.3.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <!--CUSTOM SCRIPTS-->
    <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/login.js"></script>
    <script src="home/home.js"></script>
    <script src="foundermessage/founder.js"></script>
    <script src="rooms/rooms.js"></script>
    <script src="facilities/facilities.js"></script>
    <script src="rules/rules.js"></script>
    <script src="virtual/virtual.js"></script>
    <script src="directions/directions.js"></script>
    <script src="apply/apply.js"></script>
    <script src="contact/contact.js"></script>
    <script src="residents/residents.js"></script>
    <script src="gallery/gallery.js"></script>


<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase.js"></script>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
    /*jslint vars: true, plusplus: true, devel: true, nomen: true, indent: 4, maxerr: 50 */
/*global define */
/*global angular */
// DEFINING ANGULAR MODULE ngCookies
/*jshint sub:true*/
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'home', 'founder', 'rooms', 'facilities', 'rules', 'virtual', 'directions', 'apply', 'contact', 'residents', 'gallery', 'firebase']);

app.directive('headerFile', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'header/header.html'
    };
});

app.directive('footerFile', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'footer/footer.html'
    };
});

app.directive('slidesFile', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'slides/slides.html'
    };
});

app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
        $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
    });
}]);


app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    'use strict';

//    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });

}]);


app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
    return $firebaseAuth();
  }
]);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseObject', 'Auth', '$firebaseArray', function ($scope, firebase, $firebaseObject, Auth, $firebaseArray) {
        console.log("CONTROLLER FIRED UP");
        $scope.signin = {};
        $scope.signin.state = false;
        $scope.signin.uid = null;
        var ref = firebase.database().ref();
        $scope.userStates = $firebaseArray(ref.child("Admin"));

    // CHECKING FOR AUTHORIZATION
    Auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

            if (user) {
                $scope.signin.state = true;
                $scope.signin.uid = user.uid;
                $scope.email = user.email;
                console.log($scope.signin.uid);




            } else {
                $scope.signin.state = false
                $scope.signin.uid = null
            }
        })

    // signin with email
        $scope.signInWithEmailAndPassword = function(email, password) {


            Auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then (function(firebaseuser) {


                var ref = firebase.database().ref();
                var data = ref.child("Admin").child(firebaseuser.uid);
                var list = $firebaseObject(data);


                list.$loaded().then(function(data) {
                }).catch (function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
//                toaster.pop({type: 'error', title: "Error", body: error});
                });
            }).catch(function(error) {
                                    console.log(error);

//                toaster.pop({type: 'error', title: "Error", body: error.message});
            });




        };
}]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seems to be loading Firebase twice, so it run into an error when it tries to instantiate the *[DEFAULT]* app a second time around

Remove the second loading of `firebase.js` at the bottom of your html file

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh... OHHHHHHHHHHH
Thanks

Comment: Well it did kind of help me out, though it was not the problem. The real problem here was that angularfire was also being fired up right after firebase, so when I removed the angularfire js file it couldn't find the firebase module in the app.js. So all i needed to do was load the angularfire after everything had been loaded.